# Raspberry Pi 3 GUI interface button and LED lights

Tags: python, tkinter, raspberry-pi, led

I have an assignment that consists of programming my Raspberry Pi to have 2 LED lights turn on with individual buttons on a bread board. Then I am to create a way to activate these lights remotely as well.

First problem I have in my first file is that the Button1 does turn the green light on but it does not stay on. Button2 does turn on the red light and it stays on (I used the same code so I'm a bit baffled). I need both lights to stay on until I press the individual buttons again.

Second problem I have, I created a GUI using Tkinter and the red button turns the green light on as well as the green button. I get an error code that says: 'int' object does not support item assignment button 2. I need the red button on the GUI to the correspond to the red LED and the green respectively.

Here is the code for both files. I was hoping someone with a better set of eyes than my newbie eyes could catch where I may have gone wrong? Thanks in advance:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from time import sleep
GPIO.setwarnings(False)

button1=16
button2=12
LED1=22
LED2=18

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(button1,GPIO.IN,pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(button2,GPIO.IN,pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(LED1,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(LED2,GPIO.OUT)

BS1=False
BS2=False
while(1):
    if GPIO.input(button1)==0:
        print("holiday light 1 activated")
        if BS1==False:
            GPIO.output(LED1,True)
            BS1=True
            sleep(.5)
    else:
            GPIO.output(LED1,False)
            BS1=False
            sleep(.5)
    if GPIO.input(button2)==0:
        print("holiday light 2 activated")
        if BS2==False:
            GPIO.output(LED2,True)
            BS2=True
            sleep(.5)
        else:
            GPIO.output(LED2,False)
            BS2=False
            sleep(.5)
```

Second file:

```
import tkFont
import Tkinter as tk

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setwarnings(False)

LED1=22
LED2=18

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(LED1,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(LED2,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(LED1,GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.output(LED2,GPIO.LOW)

win = tk.Tk()

myFont = tkFont.Font(family = 'Courier', size = 18, weight = 'bold')



def ledON():
   print("holiday button 1")
   if GPIO.input(18) :
    GPIO.output(18,GPIO.LOW)
    LED1["Ornament"] = "Lights On"

   else:
        GPIO.output(18,GPIO.HIGH)
        LED1["Ornament"] = "Lights Off"


def ledON():
   print("holiday button 2")
   if GPIO.input(22) :
        GPIO.output(22,GPIO.LOW)
        LED2["Ornament"] = "Lights On"

   else:
        GPIO.output(22,GPIO.HIGH)
        LED2["Ornament"] = "Lights Off"

def exitProgram():
    print("Exit Button pressed")
    GPIO.cleanup()
    win.quit()


win.title("Remote Controlled Ornament")
win.geometry('640x480')
win.configure(background='Green')

Button = tk.Button(win, text = 'button press')


exitButton = tk.Button(win, text = "Exit", fg="Blue", font = myFont, command = exitProgram, height =2 , width =20)
exitButton.pack()

ledButton1 = tk.Button(win, text = "Red Light", fg="Firebrick3", font = myFont, command = ledON, height = 2, width =14 )
ledButton2 = tk.Button(win, text = "Green Light", fg="Green", font = myFont, command = ledON, height = 2, width =14 )
ledButton1.pack()
ledButton2.pack()



win.mainloop()
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: in first file has different indentations in lines `else:` so it can change every thing and buttons may work different.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: you define function `LedON` two times so second definition replaces first definition. You have to use different names - ie `def ledRedON`, `def ledGreenON`. And then you have to use these different names in `command=`

Comment: @furas thank you so much!! I'm going to give it a whirl and post a pix of my success if it all works out. You're the best!!!

Comment: @furas, it worked!!! you're awesome possum. I don't have a way to show you pics but both files actually worked!! Thanks so much. I spent days configuring it all so this was a huge help. kudos to you

Answer (score 0):

In first file you have different indentations in lines `else:` so it can change everything and buttons may work different.

You define function `LedON` two times so second definition replaces first definition. You have to use different names - ie `def ledRedON`, `def ledGreenON`. And then you have to use these different names in `command=`